# Local Bitmap in Multithreaded WinForm Application causes error 'Object is currently in use elsewhere.'

Tags: c#

I am trying to plot graph in a multi threaded way. I have tried locking and looked at many stackoverflow questions and existing MSDN forums. My question where else is my graph being used other than the thread. Also there is only one instance of the thread running.

I have already tried locking and disposing off bitmap when thread exits. Also copying graph to a temp variable and then using it in the image box. Also sometimes i get the error so i'm guessing it is a bit of race around condition.

```
    void show_graph()
    {
        int value;
        int i;
        Bitmap graph;
        IntPtr pixel_value = new IntPtr(0);
        graph = new Bitmap(1000, 400, 4, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb, pixel_value);
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5);
            if (termination_flag)
                break;

            for (i = 0; i < data_size; i++)
            {

                lock (lockObject)
                {
                    graph.SetPixel(i, temp_graph_data[i], Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0));
                }
                value = (int)(data[i] / 10) + 200;
                temp_graph_data[i] = Convert.ToInt16(value);
                lock (lockObject)
                {
                    graph.SetPixel(i, value, Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0));
                }
            }
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                graph_pbox.Image = (Image)graph;
            }
        }
        graph.Dispose();
    }
```

I am getting an error "Object is being used elsewhere" at line
graph.SetPixel(i, temp_graph_data[i], Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0));

Also i don't have this problem if i comment out graph_pbox.Image=(Image)graph;
Why is it happening and how to overcome this?

Comment: The picture box is what is using the bitmap. You can't `SetPixel` on it after you assign it to a picturebox. As you have probably seen during your research, you should `Clone()` the bitmap before assigning it to the picturebox. BTW, `graph` is a local variable so it is thread safe. `temp_graph_data` most likely isn't though. I'd write an answer but I see other potential problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot. From what I've read from different forums normal variables are generally thread safe. The problem occurs when the variable is a graphics. Anyway I will try your solution and clone it. Also what other potential problem do you see?

Comment: You may have an infinite loop, I don't see what might be setting the `termination_flag`. I don't see the reason for the `while` loop anyway, I don't think it will yield expected results with that inner loop over `temp_graph_data`.

Comment: I have taken care of the while using the termination flag which is set to true in the "Stop" button and the destroy all resources function.